# how to determine if a tiff was written in bigtiff format

Tags: tiff, libtiff

BigTIFF isn't supported in all image readers, and I'd like to identify files based on their TIFF format. How can I determine whether an existing tiff file was written in the standard TIFF format, or instead uses the BigTIFF format?

Comment: Are you looking to do this in a particular language or at the console/terminal/etc?

Comment: I was not wed to a method in any particular language, I just wanted something I could run over a large number of files. In the end, I found something that worked in python, and since I didn't see any other questions that covered this topic, posted that as an answer.

Comment: Oh thanks, I had forgotten I could accept my own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python library [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) reads TIFF files, and one of the attributes indicates the format of the TIFF.

```
filename = '/path/to/filename.tif'
import tifffile
def is_bigtiff(filename):
    with tifffile.TiffFile(f) as img:
        return img.is_bigtiff
```

`tifffile` is just reading the first few bytes of the tiff header to determine whether it is BigTIFF, so the logic is easy to recreate without the whole library (which I just realized upon looking at the source for the library, and from which the following is drawn).

```
import struct

def is_bigtiff(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        header = f.read(4)
    byteorder = {b'II': '<', b'MM': '>', b'EP': '<'}[header[:2]]
    version = struct.unpack(byteorder + "H", header[2:4])[0]
    return version == 43
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could do is just simply look at the file extension, since the TIFF spec says "don't use .tif for anything other than a TIFF 6.0 file" (my wording but it's in there).

Oh wait, the universe ignored the specification...

You didn't specify a language or toolkit, so here's some info from the file format: see http://bigtiff.org